# Lâcher prise, c'est (de) ne pas tenir les portes

Tags: de

My transit company currently runs an ad campaign, based on a local show called "Lâcher prise". They want people to behave, i.e. not hold the trains' door open. One of their ad features the line:

*Lâcher prise, c'est ne pas tenir les portes.*

I somewhat expected this to read

*Lâcher prise, c'est de ne pas tenir les portes.*

Kind of like "L'important c'est de ne pas...". What's the rule on the usage of *de* in those cases and similar cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is correct,

> *Lâcher prise, c'est ne pas tenir les portes.*

There is a play of words with the expression *lâcher prise* which is usually figurative (let go, abandon, relax) but on the opposite very concrete here (refrain from holding the doors).

With *de*, the sentence sounds incorrect :

> *Lâcher prise, c'est <s>de</s> ne pas tenir les portes.*

although with *l'important*, it would be required:

> *L'important, c'est de ne pas tenir les portes.*

The latter can be rephrased as:

> *Il est important **de** ne pas tenir les portes.*

but you can't say

> *<s>Il est lâcher-prise</s> de ne pas tenir les portes.*

Here are some quotes built without *de*. The sentence starts with an infinitive:

> - *Partir, c'est mourir un peu.* Edmond Haraucourt
> - *Toucher, c'est jouer.* (Chess rule)
> - *Aimer, ce n'est pas se regarder l'un l'autre, c'est regarder ensemble dans la même direction.* Antoine de Saint-Exupéry
> - *Bien jouer c'est ne pas jouer... C'est très facile !* Simone Signoret

and some other with *de*; the sentence starts with a noun phrase:

> - *Le chemin le plus court d'un point à un autre c'est de ne pas y aller.* Philippe Geluck
> - *L'esprit d'une bête, c'est de ne pas être sot.* Victor Hugo
> - *La règle pour faire les liaisons, c'est de ne pas avoir l'air d'un serin.* Jules Renard

Comment: Mais, pourquoi? Pourquoi un cas prend-t-il le _de_, mais pas l'autre. Et comment savoir, en général, si le _de_ est nécessaire?

Comment: *Lâcher prise* est une locution verbale, c'est techniquement un verbe, comme dans  *partir, c'est mourir un peu*. On met en parallèle deux infinitifs. Ce n'est pas le cas avec *l'important*.

Comment: on dirait pourtant `Le lâcher prise, c'est de ne pas tenir les portes`

Comment: @OznOg Justement, si on utilise *lâcher prise* comme un substantif (ce que j'aurais un peu de mal à faire ici), on se retrouve dans un cas similaire à *l'important, c'est...*, il n'y a plus de symétrie.

Comment: @suiiurisesse 150 pages sur *le lâcher-prise* ici: https://corpus.ulaval.ca/jspui/bitstream/20.500.11794/30206/1/34448.pdf ...

Answer (score 2):

The role of "de" here is a "determinant", it's like "Lacher prise", TO not hold the trains door open.

But in French if you delete the "de" the sentence have no sens.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. I would not use *de* here. However, I will let others explain the rules.

Comment: I'm purely french so trust me lol

Comment: I am purely French myself, in Brittany :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is not simple and the sense given to « de » is determinant in deciding some of the cases. Often the rules are also valid for « est ».

The relation, in all cases is a defining one in the sense of defining what's  before « c'est » as what is after; for instance in « le souhait de voir du pays » the syntagm « voir du pays » is being defined as a particular "souhait" (a wish; the wish is to visit foreign lands.)

**I** When the core of the nominal syntagm is a noun (intention, espoir, …) « de » is used when the noun calls for « de » in a construction where it is the core of a syntagm built according to the same relation (le souhait de faire des économies, …).

- La fin(, c')est **de** ne plus former de nouveau adeptes. (*« fin » en tant que « but », la fin d'y voir clairement*)
- Son intention(, c')est **de** franchir la barrière. (*intention de franchir la barrière*)
- Leur espoir(, c')est **de** partir tôt. (*l'espoir de faire qqc*)
- Leur condition(, c')est partir avant que le jour soit fini. (*<s>la condition de qqc, la condition de faire qqc</s>*)
- Le souhait de l'équipe(, c')est **de** rentrer chez eux de bonne heure. (*souhait de revanche, souhait de la réussite de qqn, souhait de la fin des combats, …*)
- L'ordre, c'est **de** retourner à la caserne.
- Le raisonnement, c'est ne pas fumer pour ne pas se faire repérer.
- Notre chance, c'est **d**'avoir vu le pays avant les transformations.
- La conclusion, c'est faire ce que l'on peut si on le veut.
- La fin, c'est commencer une nouvelle étape. (*« fin » en tant que ce qui caractérise la dernière étape*)
- Leur plus chère entreprise, c'était rendre ce sport possible sur tout le territoire.

**II** « De » is never used when the  action or state is represented by a syntagm in which the core is an infinitive.

- Lâcher prise, c'est ne pas tenir les portes.
- Pétrir, c'est presser avec ses mains encore et encore.
- Marcher, c'est mettre un pied devant l'autre plusieurs fois.
- Marcher sur des œufs, c'est être dans une situation où on peut à tout moment causer une catastrophe.
- Avoir de l'instruction, c'est avoir l'idée générale des choses et savoir où trouver le reste.

**III** When the core of the nominal syntagm is an adjective (important, essentiel, sûr, rare,  …) « de » is used; this is so because it is always necessary to construct the impersonal adjectival form with « de »; there aren't many adjectives that can be used in this way, and most need to be used in a superlative construction;

- L'important(, c')est de se rappeler. (*Il est important de se rappeler.*)
- L'essentiel(, c')est de ne pas avoir peur. (*Il est essentiel de ne pas avoir peur.*)
- Le plus sûr(, c')est de suivre la route indiquée. (*Il est plus sûr de suivre la route indiquée.*)
- Le plus rare(, c')est de trouver une solution facile. (*Il est plus rare de trouver une solution facile.*)
- Le moins difficile pour eux(, c')est de travailler seuls. (*Il est moins difficile de travailler seul.*)
- <s>Le capital, c'est d'y arriver avant demain.</s> (*Il est capital d'y arriver avant demain.*)